# What is the name of the ubuntu server cli installer?

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to debug some ubuntu installation issues from a customized ISO using the source image for ubuntu server 18.04 here:
http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04.2/ubuntu-18.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso (I am doing the customization similar to how Cubic is done).

When I run the installation after my customization and repackaging, I am selecting the first option 'Install Ubuntu Server' and proceed with a text based installer.

My question: What is the name of this CLI based installer?

I have run across Ubuiquity, Subiquity, curtin and debian installer names while doing searches for the issue I am trying to chase down, and I basically want to find this installer's name and source to continue troubleshooting.

Bonus: I would love a link to this installer's source.

Comment: The screenshot you have posted does not show the UI used by the live server ISO. This is how the live server's installer UI looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHkfj.png What you've shown is debian-installer with (IIRC) the newt frontend, used by (non-live) server, netinst and minimal ISOs. Please clarify what you're actually using.

Comment: @muru Thanks, I removed the screenshot to avoid confusing people. You have helped me clear up my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That ISO ("`live-server`") uses Subiquity, as [the Release Notes state](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#Server_installer):

> #### Server installer
>
> The next generation [Subiquity](https://github.com/CanonicalLtd/subiquity) server installer, brings the
>   comfortable live session and speedy install of Ubuntu Desktop to
>   server users at last.

The source code is also linked to by the Release Notes: https://github.com/CanonicalLtd/subiquity